# Copy specific part of a browser URL Bar

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out a way to copy only a specific part from the URL Bar, any assistance is appreciated!

The link goes something like

https://internal.dummysite.com/compliance/accounts/ACCOUNTNAME/#photos

I want the command to copy the /ACCOUNTNAME/ bit from the link. |

Tried something like:

```js
var el = document.createElement('a');
el.href = "https://internal.DUMMYSITE.com/compliance/account/ACCOUNTNAME/#photos";

el.host        // www.internal.DUMMYSITE.com
el.hostname    // www.DUMMYSITE.com
el.hash        // #photos
el.href        // https://internal.DUMMYSITE.com/compliance/account/search?filter=a/#photos
el.pathname    // /show/search
el.protocol    // http:
el.search      // ?filter=a
```

Now I'll have you know that I'm a complete beginner so please don't murder me on the comments, all help is appreciated and massive thanks in advance for anyone willing to assist.

Cheers!

Comment: When you say copy, are you looking to copy the value to the clipboard, or are you looking to simply parse out the value?

Comment: So I'm supposed to check accounts for violations, and put them from one browser to the other, selecting everything using a mouse is a pain in the neck so I want to make a shortcut that will copy the account name on the clipboard.

Comment: I've answered accordingly. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Massive thanks, will give it a try now, if I run into any issues I'll let you know!

Comment: Also sorry if it is too much, do I have to replace anything from the code you provided, or do I simply shove it in on tampermonkey XD

Comment: Alright so the URL Format is exactly as described, I'm using a plugin called AutoControl where I can add a keyboard shortcut and run a script. So the shortcut is all set, I need only the script that will copy the path that was mentioned up above to the clipboard. Sorry for not clarifying it sooner

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to just use a regular expression.

```js
const regex = /account\/(.*)\/#photos/gm;
const str = `https://internal.DUMMYSITE.com/compliance/account/ACCOUNTNAME/#photos`;
let m = regex.exec(str);
console.log(m[1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, it would appear that it does great in getting the part of the URL that I need, 

How do I go about adding some extra code to copy it to clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = "https://internal.DUMMYSITE.com/compliance/account/ACCOUNTNAME/#photos"

// Split url every /
const urlSplitted = url.split('/')

// Remove last if begins with #
if (urlSplitted[urlSplitted.length - 1].startsWith('#'))
    urlSplitted.pop()

// Get last url 
const urlPart = urlSplitted.pop()
```

**Note!** `urlSplitted` is not usable anymore, because .pop is mutable and removes the last item. Use `urlSplitted[urlSplitted.length - 1]` to get the latest item without removing it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code, tested it out, however I'm getting an error on the last row

"urlPart" is defined but never used, how to proceed?

Comment: @mesnapie it is defined but never used. You just have to just the variable and the warning will be gone.

Comment: Sorry if I am bothering, how do I just the variable, like I said I'm a newb in this field xD